# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio connection error

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014

I am getting an error while opening the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio:

> named pipe error 40( Microsoft SQL server could not connect) Microsoft SQL server error: 67.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: If you just Googled the exact error you're getting, the first result is a lengthy article detailing possible causes and fixes...

Comment: I have installed it on windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:
1) You entered an invalid Server Name\named Instance.
2) You installed MS SQL SERVER 2014 in a PC joined in a domain where the user has restrictions in accessing through the Database, because most of domains controller/server have installed SQL SERVER Express edition on it.

If you want to ask how I know about the reasons, it's because I experienced the same problem as before and talked directly to our System Admin/Head IT Department about the issue.